# Batch File: Copy text line to multiple files

Tags: batch-file, io-redirection

I would like to copy a text line to multiple files.

I have tried:

```
echo .anyclass {color:red;} >> "\\servername\stylesheet1.css" >> "\\servername\stylesheet2.css" >> "\\servername\stylesheet3.css"
```

but it seems that the operator **>>** is not usable multiple times starting from one object.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description; please read the article [mcve]! Anyway, what you are looking for is a [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html): for %I in ("C:\stylesheet*.css") do >> "%~I" echo .anyclass {color:red;}`; do not forget to double each `%`-sign if you're using this code in a batch file rather than executing it directly in command prompt...

Comment: (@aschipfl I "borrowed" your code to complete my answer)

Comment: Fine for me, @Stephan! ;-)

Comment: @aschipfl: Thanks for your hint. I have tried to rephrase it. But please excuse me if I described it wrong, as I have clearly no knowledge about Batch files.

Comment: That's way better, thank you! Take a look at this: [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: I gotta thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't redirect to several destinations at the same time.

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,3) do (
  echo .anyclass {color:red;} >> "\\servername\stylesheet%%a.css" 
)
```

or

```
for %%a in (stylesheet1 stylesheet2 stylesheet3) do (
  echo .anyclass {color:red;} >> "\\servername\%%a.css"
)
```

will echo the string to all three files. The first loop uses an increasing number (some languages have a more understandable syntax: `for a=1 to 3 step 1`), the second one iterates over strings. Which one you use, is up to you.

**EDIT**
While I was writing this, aschifpl came up with another version, which might be better (or not): (writing to *all existing* `stylesheet*.css`) (I'll borrow it for completeness):

```
for %%a in ("C:\stylesheet*.css") do 
  >> "%~a" echo .anyclass {color:red;}
)
```